# Partial derivative vs normal derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose we have

$z = x^2y + e^{3 x y} + 2t$,

then we should (or at least the way I understand it) have
$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2xy + 3ye^{3xy}$.

Now what if I go and state further that

$x = 2t^2, y = -t$

Would this change the value of$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$? Would it change the value of $\frac{dz}{dx}$? Are these two quantities different in these two cases? I always thought the use of $d$ vs $\partial$ was just notational.

Comment: It only would change $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}$.